# CMakelist Shared file(.so) linking failure

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmakelists-options

I have a requirement to link  c project (which includes prebuilt.so file) to flutter (Android).

Everything is compiling and linking OK, i.e. the project is building successfully,and it creating .so file in app data directory and also i can able to see prebuilt .so file in data directory.

But while calling generated .so file from dart getting below error

**Error:**

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'libproject_test.so': dlopen failed: library "../../../../../../abc/c/lib/x86_64/libfoo.so" not found: 
needed by /data/app/~~E_RgTYnWY_n0rO3CPrDIcQ==/com.example.c_test-QMxh40AMbU33cxiYyUxgQQ==/lib/x86_64/libproject_test.so in namespace classloader-namespace
```

**below is the my CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library( project_test
        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED
        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${ALL_FILES} )

add_library(libfoo SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libfooPROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../abc/c/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libfoo.so"
        )


target_link_libraries(project_test
       libfoo
)
```

Comment: Question is unclear
Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a requirement to link c project (which includes prebuilt.so file) to flutter.

Everything is compiling and linking OK, i.e. the project is building successfully,and it creating .so file in app data directory and also i can able to see prebuilt .so file in data directory.

But while calling generated .so file from dart it giving error

Comment: Please dont add additional or clarification details as comments, rather edit your question to add this information. It makes it easier for others to understand what you are attempting to achieve. I see you have done that so the comment is unncessary.